# How to setup react native to use flow?

Tags: reactjs-native

I was wondering how I have to setup .flowConfig in order to use flow on a React- Native project.  I created an empty .flowConfig file but as soon as I include the react-native module in a JS source file and check this file with flow, flow displays a 'not_found' error message.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the instructions on https://flowtype.org/ to create your projects `.flowconfig` file, you can copy and paste it, you also have to install flow via `brew install flow` and add the flow binaries to your `package.json`, once you've done all this, you should be able to manually run flow and check for error types, but, that is not really optimal.

I haven't been able to set up flow on atom without using nuclide, I'm guessing with some digging around the packages you can find something that works that allows for on-the-fly flow checking.

The link provided by @jerome (https://egghead.io/lessons/react-setup-nuclide-to-use-flow-and-eslint-mac) is useful but only for nuclide installation, still worth a watch.

Answer (score 1):

I advise to watch https://egghead.io/lessons/react-setup-nuclide-to-use-flow-and-eslint-mac it explains how to use Flow with Nuclide. I had issue to make flow works and my main mistake was that I didn't install flow (brew install flow). On the official site (https://flowtype.org/docs/getting-started.html) they don't mention you need to install flow (or it is not super obvious if it is the case).
Anyway watch the video it is great, it even explains ESLint :)

Comment: actually the correct way to install flow globally is not with homebrew (as only a few version of flow are available) but with "npm install -g flow-bin@0.38.0" (use the version mentioned in your .flowconfig)